# Understanding 「女神を信じてここまで来たのだろう」

Tags: meaning, て-form

Context: The group is going to be attacked and one of the people is worried whether they will lose the fight or not and then the leader says what's below.

「祈りを持って戦うのだ。正しき者が負けるわけがない。女神を信じてここまで来たのだろう」
and then he responds with 「は、はい……」

My problem is understanding the last part of what he said "女神を信じてここまで来たのだろう". I'm not quite sure how to interpret it. Does the 女神を信じてここまで来た part mean that it is through their belief in the goddesses that they/he have come so far(and so the goddesses will help them win) or does it mean that because they/he believe in the goddesses they have come this far?

One of the problems I'm having is that in Japanese things are often left out e.g. in this case 同士 to refer to the believer (there's probably a more suitable one than that) or 我々 for the group. How does one determine whether he is speaking about the group or just the believer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have pretty much answered your question. It could mean both the things you have stated depending on the tone of the leader's voice. Given the fact that one of the comrade responds 「は、はい……」, I take that the leader is saying "we have believed in the goddess and come this far haven't we?".

Answer (score 0):

> through their belief in the goddesses that they/he have come so far(and so the goddesses will help them win)

I think this is your answer. If you read the whole thing, he orders the comrads to **fight with prayers** (I am not quite sure how to translate this. "You will fight with your prayers equipped"). So you will win because the goddess will help you. Also says "There is no way that the righteous ones(=believers of the goddess) will lose"